# Is there any recommended asana for a student studying any branch of knowledge from a book?

Tags: scripture, hatha-yoga

It is customary to study from a book for gaining knowledge.

Is there any asana recommended by Hindu scriptures in this context?

Comment: Brahma Sutras IV.I.7 - Worship is possible in a sitting position. Also Swami Vivekananda quotes in the Appendix at the end of his translation of Patanjali's Yoga Sutras, Sankhya Book VI.24 - Any posture which is easy and steady is an Asana; there is no other rule.